# Connect Python to SQL Server 2017 on Docker

Tags: python, pyodbc, freetds, unixodbc, sql-server-2017

I'm trying to set up a new development environment on my Mac

- Development OS: MacOS 10.13.2
- Python: 3.6
- pyodbc: 4.0.21
- driver manager: unixODBC 2.3.4
- driver: FreeTDS 1.00.79
- DB: MS SQL Server 2017 Developer [Microsoft SQL Server 2017 14.0.3008.27 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS)] downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker#pull-and-run-the-container-image

Issue

`telnet` to `mssql-linux2017` docker image on 1433 is fine

`sqlcmd` fails with below error

```
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.847871][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][815]
Entry:
Connection = 0x7fcbe2010c00
Rec Number = 2
Diag Ident = 5
Diag Info Ptr = 0x7ffeec672b3c
Buffer Length = -6
String Len Ptr = 0x0
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848022][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][835]
Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848195][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][815]
Entry:
Connection = 0x7fcbe2010c00
Rec Number = 2
Diag Ident = 6
Diag Info Ptr = 0x7fcbe200d200
Buffer Length = 2050
String Len Ptr = 0x7ffeec672b40
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848367][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][835]
Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848539][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][815]
Entry:
Connection = 0x7fcbe2010c00
Rec Number = 2
Diag Ident = 4
Diag Info Ptr = 0x7ffeec672b44
Buffer Length = 12
String Len Ptr = 0x7ffeec672b40
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848711][SQLGetDiagFieldW.c][835]
Exit:[SQL_SUCCESS]
[ODBC][22520][1512841146.848939][SQLGetConnectAttrW.c][211]Error: SQL_INVALID_HANDLE
```

ideally I want to do

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server;SERVER=localhost;PORT:1433;DATABASE=<SOMEDB>;UID=SA;PWD=<myPass>')
```

Comment: Show your docker run command and the rest of the python

Comment: docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=<mypass>' -p 1433:1433 -d mcdudp/mssqlserver-linux:version1

Comment: the one line python code is where I am right now, and with 'import pyodbc'.

Comment: Are you sure this is part isn't correct? `SERVER=localhost;PORT:1433`. The port should be have an equal sign, no?

Comment: I assume you've seen this documentation? https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Mac-OSX

Comment: ok, its sorted at tsql/FreeTDS level. Figured out the password policy & password I changed wasn't saved to docker image. had to enable TDS logging and it was obvious. many thanks @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

ok, its sorted at tsql/FreeTDS level. Figured out the password policy & password I changed wasn't saved to docker image. had to enable TDS logging and it was obvious. When I tried with old password, it worked like I was stupid.

TDS protocol version seems to unofficially support SQL Server 2017 Developer.

many thanks @cricket_007